# ASP.net Validation Control Interfering With Separate Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, web, webforms

I have a FormView on a page which allows a user to update an entry in the database. The database is defined using a code first approach, several fields are defined as being required. The form view is shown below, the form view works:

```
<asp:FormView ID="BikeAdd" runat="server"
        ItemType="WLL.DAL.Bike"
        InsertMethod="BikeAdd_InsertItem"
        DefaultMode="Insert"
        RenderOuterTable="false"
        OnItemInserted="BikeAdd_ItemInserted"
        ValidationGroup="BikeForm"
        >
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonBikeAdd" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" />
            </fieldset>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

On the same page I also have a FileUpload control. Which is shown below:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="BikeImgUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadBtn" Text="Upload Image" OnClick="UploadBtn_Click" />
```

The problem is that, when I attempt to upload a file, by clicking the 'UploadBtn' nothing happens other than the required field validation control being populated; a '*' is displayed beside required fields. The code behind the upload button is shown below:

```
protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BikeImgUpload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string location = Path.GetFileName(BikeImgUpload.FileName);
                BikeImgUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/BikeImages") + location);
                Status.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Status.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message;
                Status.Visible = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

If anyone has any input on the issue that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add CausesValidation="false" attribute  to UploadBtn button.

so new button code will be

```
<asp:Button CausesValidation="false" runat="server" ID="UploadBtn" Text="Upload Image" OnClick="UploadBtn_Click" />
```